# Condition as to cater with preset value in a format

Tags: vba, excel

My previous VBA code is like this

```
field9 = 00 & Format(Date, "YYYYMM") & CleanString(myVal) & _
         Format(Cells(vRow, 8).Value, "00000")
```

This field9 variable will be used to convert my excel numbers in a field
from 000000000000006(preset value) to 02017010100006 (from what i've set in field 9). The `CleanString(myVal)` i use to pass autogenerate sequence number from other module.

Currently i need to modify this thing in order to cater with my new requirement which  is 
002017010000006( preset value) to 002017010100006. I need to remain the preset value as i can't use my current code because it will have more digits. I need assistance for this.

i will further explain what the problem is.
The first part is what my variable are meant to do

```
000000000000006(pulled this from text file) to 002017010100006(vba code processed)
```

"00""201701""01""00006"
   1. preset 00 in my code
   2. 201701 is YYYYMM
   3. myval is my running sequence number 01-99
   4. i format my cell into 00000 let say if this field having 1 then it will be
   00001 
5. i can do this using my current formula

The problem now is

```
002017010000006(pulled this from text file) to 002017010100006(vba code processed)
```

1. This 002017010000006 is from a text file too
2. if i am going to use my current formula, i will having this kind of issues
   as it will be more than 15 digits 00201701012017010013676

i need solution in maintaining "201701" from my text files instead of using `Format(Date, "YYYYMM")` from my current solutions

This is the outcome i need `002017010100006` just 15 digits

p/s: i have edited my info for further understanding, as i have not cleared with my question and there's some wrong info in this too. i am sorry for the inconvenience

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `Format(Date, "000000")` - does that really work ?

Comment: oops, that's the wrong part, my code should be Format(Date, "YYYYMM"), i paste in the wrong thing just now. sorry

Comment: What? do you mean you cannot simply change `YYYYMM` to `YYYYMMDD`? Why is that?

Comment: no, i do not need the DD, the YYYYMM is a preset value in a text file, i need to maintain it. 002017010100006. the 01"01"00006 , the "01" is from my CleanString(myVal) variable, if i used my current field 9 variable, it will causes something like this 00201701012017010000006. instead of 002017010100006

Comment: Stil not clear, well, does it solve your problem if I give you a way to transform a string in the form `002017010000006` into another string in the form `002017010100006`, where the last `01` can be any two digits number?

Comment: i need solution in maintaining "201701" from my text files instead of using Format(Date, "YYYYMM") from my current solutions( this is the previous solution in replacing the 000000 with YYYYMM, if i din maintain the 201701 from my text file and use  this Format(Date, "YYYYMM") in my current code, it will be something like this 00201701012017010000006. it's more than 15 digits, i just need to maintain this format 002017010100006

Comment: ok, i can give you a statement that keeps the first 8 digits (say `00201701`, then puts after them a two digits of your choice (say `01`), then keeps the remaining 5 digits (say `00006`)). Does that do it?

Comment: yes it can do, the 01 have to be from my CleanString(myVal) and the 00006 is from Format(Cells(vRow, 8).Value, "00000").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Function Transform(initial As String) As String
    Transform = Left(initial, 8) & CleanString(myVal) & Format(Cells(vRow, 8).Value, "00000")
End Function
```

or simply assign it to a variable...

```
newString = Left(oldString, 8) & CleanString(myVal) & Format(Cells(vRow, 8).Value, "00000")
```

Be aware that your `CleanString(myVal)` has to be a string of length 2. If it has *any* length, it still needs some modification (i.e. with a 3 digits value, the final number will be on 16 digits)

So if you want to allow that `CleanString` have more than two digits, do this to keep always a 15 digits length:

```
    Dim s As String: s = CleanString(myVal)
    newString= Left(oldString, 8) & s & Format(Cells(vRow, 8).Value, String(7 - Len(s), "0"))
```

Comment: yes, that's what i need, but after apply this thing, i've met another problem. i will post another thread for that problem.