# Numeric format problems as the number ran to the 2nd digit

Tags: excel, vba

i have a problem
The numbers supposed to be generate in a format 
i've attached the link here as for reference
[Condition as to cater with preset value in a format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41709701/condition-as-to-cater-with-preset-value-in-a-format/41710822#41710822)

The solutions given by A.S.H is

```
Dim s As String: s = CleanString(myVal)
field8 = Left(oldstring, 6) & s & Format(Cells(vRow, 8).Value, String(7 - Len(s), "0"))
```

Before using the Solutions provided by A.S.H, i am using this code, it's working, due to some changes in requirement i have to change the code.

```
field3 = 0 & 0 & Format(Date, "YYYYMM") & CleanString(myVal) & Format(Cells(vRow, 3).Value, "00000")
```

Yes indeed it work out for the code provided by A.S.H, but the problem is the output when i generate the numbers from the statement above.

The current output which is wrong as the numbers 01 is in the first two digits, the 01 is a passing value from myVal.
**01**2017010000001

The correct output should be
00201701**01**00001

The original CleanString code is in the same form module as the part i am having problem is( The code are just for reference to shows what i am doing)

```
Function CleanString(strIn As String) As String
Dim objRegex
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
 .Global = True
 .Pattern = "[^\d]+"
CleanString = .Replace(strIn, vbNullString)
End With
 End Function
```

The myVal code is as below which is on other module which generate increment numbers

```
Public myVal As String
Sub test()
Dim fn As String, txt As String, temp
fn = ThisWorkbook.Path + "\PaymentFile01.txt"
If fn = "False" Then Exit Sub
txt = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(fn).ReadAll
With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "_(\d+)(?=\|)"
    myVal = Format$(.Execute(txt)(0).submatches(0) + 1, "_00")
    txt = .Replace(txt, myVal)
    .Pattern = "(\r\n)+$"
    Open Replace(fn, ".txt", ".txt") For Output As #1
        Print #1, txt;
        MsgBox "This is bathch No" & myVal
    Close #1
End With
End Sub
```

Not Sure which part went wrong. In my opinion, the Solutions Given by A.S.H requires some modifications to cater with my requirement.

Thank you in advance first.

Comment: You need to be more precise. Post a minimal and complete problem statement and code you tried. Don't ask the SO community to debug the code for you

Comment: The code are just for references about what i am doing, i just need some advice and some tips guidance for this problem. That's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i did it, i found the solution for this, Simple as this

```
field8 = 0 & 0 & Left(Cells(vRow, 8).Value, 6) & CleanString(myVal) & Format(Right((Cells(vRow, 8).Value), 5), "00000")
```